# How can I include FirstOrDefault child of parent in Entity Framework linq ".Include"

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I want to select Evaluation with all his Component and only the first Answers of each component.

```
QueryFutureEnumerable<Evaluation> deferredEvaluations = db.Evaluations
    .Include(e => e.Components)
    .Include(e => e.Components.Select(c => c.Answers).FirstOrDefault())
    .Where(e => e.Deprecated == false)
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.LastModified)
    .Future();
```

I need help figuring how to Include only first Answer child.

Here is what I already tried which does not works:

```
 .Include(e => e.Components.Select(c => new List<Answer>(){ c.Answers.FirstOrDefault()} ))
 .Include(e => e.Components.Select(c => new { Answer = c.Answers.FirstOrDefault()}))
 .Include(e => e.Components.Select(c => c.Answers.Take(1)))
```

Note: I'm using Z.EntityFramework.Plus; but I don't think the part of the query that I want to accomplish has anything to do with that.

When it's not workin, "I get the error: The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type..."

Comment: No you can't filter on navigational properties when you're eager loading them.

Comment: @CodeNotFound ok thank you!